# Alternating values from two arrays into a new third array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm on my third week of learning Javascript and got an assignment that's giving me some trouble.

I'm supposed to create a function called mix that takes two parameters that are two arrays. When called the function should return a new list which alternates between the two previous arrays (see example below).

This is about arrays and loops so I need to use those. also, I'm only allowed to use the array functions: push, pop, shift & unshift.

My teacher said that this is solved the easiest using a while loop.

#### Example

```
mix([], []) === []

mix([2, 4], []) === [2, 4]

mix([], [8, 16]) === [8, 16]

mix([1, 3, 5], [2, 4]) === [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

mix([10, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c']) === [10, 'a', 9, 'b', 'c']
```

Before I got the tip about the easiest being a while loop I started trying with a for a loop. The problem I'm having here is that it works as long as the arrays are the same length, but I'm having trouble understanding how I can solve it so the arrays can have different lengths.

Since I'm trying to learn I want pointers in the right direction and not the whole answer!

Please excuse my chaotic beginner code :)

#### My current code

```
function mix(array1, array2) {
    let newList = [];
    for(i = 0; i < array1.length || i < array2.length; i++) {
        if(array1.length > 0 || array2.length > 0){
            newList.push( array1[i] );
            newList.push( array2[i] );
            
        }
        
    }
    return newList;
}   
mix([10, 9],['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I would also like a pointer for how a while loop would be easier and how i would go about using that instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not far from solution. My best advice would be to ask your teacher directly, he's there to teach you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your current code, you need to *separately* check whether `i < array1.length` (and if so, push `array1[i]`), and *also* do the same sort of test for `array2`:

```js
function mix(array1, array2) {
  let newList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length || i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (i < array1.length) {
      newList.push(array1[i]);
    }
    if (i < array2.length) {
      newList.push(array2[i]);
    }
  }
  return newList;
}
console.log(mix([10, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Make sure to declare the `i` with `let i`, else you'll implicitly create a global variable (or throw an error in strict mode).

To do this with a `while` loop, I'd loop while either array has a length, and `shift` (remove the `[0]`th item) from them:

```js
function mix(array1, array2) {
  const newList = [];
  while (array1.length || array2.length) {
    if (array1.length) {
      newList.push(array1.shift());
    }
    if (array2.length) {
      newList.push(array2.shift());
    }
  }
  return newList;
}
console.log(mix([10, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This cleared it all up. Hate how obvious it seems now that i have it in front of me. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do much better with array shift, it takes first element from array and returns its value, so for example

```
const firstElement = [1, 2, 4].shift();
// firstElement - 1
// array [2, 4]
```

with this info you can now write your function like so:

```
function (arr1, arr2) {
   const resultArr = [];
   while(arr1.length && arr2.length) {
       resultArr.push(arr1.shift());
       resultArr.push(arr2.shift());
   }
   return resultArr.concat(arr1, arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
function mix(arr1,arr2) {
  var newArr=[];
  while(arr1.length>0&&arr2.length>0) {
    newArr.push(arr1.shift(),arr2.shift());
  }
  newArr.push(...arr1,...arr2);
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to consider the input arrays as a two-dimensional array.

You can then:

1. **rotate/transpose** the two-dimensional array (rows become columns); and
2. **flatten** the result (rows are concatenated into a one-dimensional array).

The transformation looks like this for the example input `[1, 3, 5], [2, 4]`:

```
              Rotate             Flatten
[1, 3, 5],      ⇒      [1, 2],      ⇒      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 4]                 [3, 4],
                       [5]
```

Or, in code:

```js
const mix = (...arrays) => {
  const transposed = arrays.reduce((result, row) => {
    row.forEach((value, i) => result[i] = [...result[i] || [], value]);
    return result;
  }, []);
  return transposed.flat();
};


console.log(mix([], [])); // === []
console.log(mix([2, 4], [])); // === [2, 4]
console.log(mix([], [8, 16])); // === [8, 16]
console.log(mix([1, 3, 5], [2, 4])); // === [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(mix([10, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c'])); // === [10, 'a', 9, 'b', 'c']
```

Benefits of this approach are that it automatically scales to allow more than two input arrays, and, unlike the shift operations, does not mutate the input arrays.